# Background fetch alternatives

Tags: ios, background

I want to my app do some computations and then communicate with external server via HTTP. I would like to perform this operations both in foreground and background. It seems that Background fetch mode is best choice for me but I have some concerns related with this. What is the minimal time interval between fetches? I read somewhere this is 10 min, is that true? I read also that when user force quit fetches are no longer invoked. Is there any walk around to this? Finally, is there any alternative to background fetch? I saw there is Newsstand mode what looks promising. Can I use it for my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use background fetch or another background mode and don't really use it for the intended use, iOS will detect that an kill your app. (the most promising mode for that would be VOIP, but this would't make it into the App Store, as it's a cheat either)

You  can start a background task, when your app enters background, what gives you 3 minutes time (iOS 7 and above).

As I did it before, you can schedule a local notification and use it to remind the user, that he should bring the app back into the foreground for more calculations, if he likes.